# Powershell - Expand-Archive and rename files as it includes invalid characters

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm having trouble unzipping an archive with powershell.

Let's say I have downloaded `file.zip`

`file.zip` has files with a "colon" in it's file names. (i.e. `foo:bar.p12`)

Using 7zip to manually unzip these files automatically replaces the colon (`:`) with an underscore (`_`). Working fine!

Using expand-archive with powershell throws the following error:

```
> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The
> given path's format is not supported." At
> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:1004
> char:52
> + ... yFileInfo = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -ArgumentList $cu ...
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

This is my code:

```bsh
$zip_location = "C:\path\to\zipfiles"
$zipfiles = Get-ChildItem $zip_location -Filter *.zip

foreach ($zip in $zipfiles) {
    Expand-Archive -Path $zip_location\$zip -DestinationPath $zip_location -Force
}
```

Is there a way to extract these files with powershell? Thank you.

Comment: What if you just change your Expand-Archive line to:
`Expand-Archive -Path $zip_location\$zip.Replace(":","_") -DestinationPath $zip_location -Force`

Comment: Just tried that. Doens't seem to work: `Expand-Archive : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:5 char:5
+     Expand-Archive -Path $zip_location\$zip.Replace(":","_") -Destina ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Expand-Archive], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Expand-Archive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ZipFile` type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58008975/712649) to extract the file(s) manually:

```bsh
# Import the containing assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

try{
  # Open the zip file with ZipFile.OpenRead()
  $zipFileItem = Get-Item .\Path\To\File.zip
  $zipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFileItem.FullName)

  foreach($entry in $zipFile.Entries){
    # Remove the `:` from any file name
    $targetFileName = $entry.Fullname -replace ':','_'

    # Create new file on disk, open writable stream
    $targetFileStream = $(
        New-Item -Path $targetFileName -ItemType File -Force
    ).OpenWrite()

    # Open stream to compressed file, copy to new file stream
    $entryStream = $entry.Open()
    $entryStream.BaseStream.CopyTo($targetFileStream)

    # Clean up
    $targetFileStream,$entryStream |ForEach-Object Dispose
  }
}
finally{
  # clean up
  if($zipFile){ $zipFile.Dispose() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works really well, except the name is being cut off. The file name (inside the zip file) looks like this `domain.com_FOO:Bar-test1_Username@domain.com_20200416.p12`. The extracted file looks like this: `Bar-test1_Username@domain.com_20200416.p12`

Comment: This is how the variables look like: `$entry.Name` = `Bar-test1_Username@domain.com_20200416.p12`
`$targetFileName` = `Bar-test1_Username@domain.com_20200416.p12`
`$entry` = `domain.com_FOO:Bar-test1_Username@domain.com_20200416.p12`

Comment: @m4xh updated answer to replace `:` on the whole `FullName` property

Comment: Alright, did some testing today and I noticed that all `.pwd` files are not being extracted properly. I can see all files in `$zip_location` but the content of these files is gibberish. If I do right click -> Properties it says `Size on Disk: 0 Bytes`. These `.pwd` files can be opened with notepad and should contain just a few lines of text. Expand-Archive works just fine. Do you have an idea what might be the issue here?